# With Jupyter Server how to handle non-interactive private key pass phrase?

Tags: python, ssl, jupyter

I’m trying to setup Jupyter server in a cloud without SSH forwarding.  SSL is a requirement.  When I setup with a valid and signed private/public key pair, I continually am prompted on the Jupyter console to input private key pass phrase whenever a request is made to the server port.

What is the non-interactive way to configure Jupyter private key pass phrase?

Was expecting standard Jupyter environment to load when connecting to server port (ie through browser or VS Code).  Instead I get propmted on Jupyter server console repeatedly:

```text
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

Comment: One way is to remove the passphrase protection entirely from the private key. You have to decide if that's acceptably secure in your environment.